# variable to store key value argument to a function

Tags: python

I have the following function and I want to know how to create variables to actually store `a=1, b=2, c=3`? So I could pass those variable to `test`?

```
def test(a, b, c):
    print (a, b, c)

test(a=1, b=2, c=3)

# Things I want to have
d="a=1"
e="b=2"
f="c=3"
test(d, e, f)
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. What do you mean by store the variables? The variables are already stored in the arguments

Comment: `args = {'a':4,'c':5,'b':6};
test(**args)`

Comment: Hi @Lemon, you can use `locals` with is a dictionary of arguments you have passed, check my answer below!

Answer (score 1):

You probably mean unpacking a dictionary? Like this:

```
def test(a, b, c):
    print (a, b, c)

test(a=1, b=2, c=3)

my_args = {"a":1, "b":2, "c":3}
test(**my_args) #Unpacks the my_args dictionary to use as the arguments to the function
```

Answer (score 0):

`locals()` is a dictionary which saves the variable name as key, and the value of the variable is stored as a value, and that dictionary can be used inside the function to print the way you want!

```
def test(a, b, c):
    print(locals())
    #{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
    for key, value in locals().items():
        print('{}={}'.format(key, value))
    print (a, b, c)

test(a=1, b=2, c=3)
#a=1
#b=2
#c=3
#1 2 3
```

Another way of calling the function `test` will be to create a dictionary of arguments, and pass them like so.

```
dct = {'a':1,'b':2,'c':3}
test(**dct)
```